# Azure CLI - delete subscription?

Tags: azure, subscription

I am looking for a way to delete Azure subscription programmatically. I'm mainly interested in Azure CLI but i can not find the way to do that in proper way.

By the way there is PowerShell Command which provide exactly needed action. [Remove-AzureSubscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/remove-azuresubscription?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no way to delete a subscription. the linked cmdlet doesn't do what you think it does:

> The Remove-AzureSubscription cmdlet deletes an Azure subscription from your subscription data file so Windows PowerShell can't find it. This cmdlet does not delete the subscription from Microsoft Azure, or change the actual subscription in any way.

only Azure Support might be able to help you, although in my case they said its impossible to delete subscriptions.

Comment: I also contacted support and they were able just to disable subscriptions and then after 90 days they "disappear". Actually the same kind of action is just "Cancel" if I understood docs correctly.

Comment: they never disappeared for me ;(

Comment: Okey "disappear" is not precise. They are grayed out:) Soooo there is no way to Cancel/ Delete / Remove subscription? C'mon :(

Comment: I have found something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/subscription/delete#code-try-0 

it's an direct call to API, I will give it a try

Comment: its api management, not subscription, here are api calls for the subscriptions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions. delete doesnt exists. its not possible

Answer (score 0):

New feature in REST API already as preview:

The operation to cancel a subscription

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions%20(preview)/cancel

Answer (score 0):

Warning from Azure portal after cancelling my subcription : You will be able to manually delete this subscription 3 days after it was initally cancelled