# Azure Delete Canceled (Disabled) Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I've canceled an Azure Subscription, but how can I remove it? I'm sure we won't use this one, it's empty and we have' got more Subscriptions to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot remove it immediately.

You need to wait 90 days before permanently deleting your data in case you need to access it or you change your mind.

Ref - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-how-to-cancel-azure-subscription#what-happens-after-i-cancel-my-subscription

---

**Besides**, `Remove-AzureSubscription` also could not do that.

See [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/remove-azuresubscription?view=azuresmps-4.0.0#description) :

> The Remove-AzureSubscription cmdlet deletes an Azure subscription from your subscription data file so Windows PowerShell can't find it. **This cmdlet does not delete the subscription from Microsoft Azure, or change the actual subscription in any way.**

### Update:

See the issue - [Cannot delete subscription](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/33173).

The Member of Microsoft Docs replied:

> You can't delete an Azure subscription directly. As the article states, all an account admin needs to do is Cancel subscription. Billing stops at that point and all Azure services get disabled, but a final invoice isn’t created until the end of the current billing period. **90 days after you cancel the subscription, Azure automatically permanently deletes the subscription and all data.**

Comment: The link doesn't say anything about deleting the subscription, only that Azure keeps the data free for 90 days. Moreover this answer says that subscription doesn't get deleted even after 90 days:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081649/azure-cli-delete-subscription

Comment: @WinBoss It says "We wait 90 days before permanently **deleting** your data in case you need to access it or you change your mind."

Comment: @JoyWang-MSFT My subscription was disabled a year ago, it is showed as disabled, but I still cannot delete it, there is no delete option, and it was not deleted automatically after 90 days.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot delete the sub. I have a subscription that is cancelled for 2 or 3 years already, and it wont go away. there were many questions like that on stack overflow, one of the recent ones I've spotted: [Azure CLI - delete subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081649/azure-cli-delete-subscription)